# How should a process running outside Internet Explorer talk to JavaScript running inside it?

Tags: internet-explorer

This may well be impossible; either way I'm sure people here will know.  I'm trying to reduce three "OK" prompts to two.

As part of my application, users will download and run an executable I supply; call it privileged.exe. privileged.exe will have a coda that asks for the highest privileges available.  That's two OK prompts, one to run privileged.exe and one for UAC.

I'd like privileged.exe to then install an ActiveX control, browser plugin or some such.  The purpose of this ActiveX control is to allow the JavaScript running inside the browser to talk to the running privileged.exe process, to allow the user to perform certain operations that require high privileges by making choices in the browser.  And I'd ideally like this to happen without the user having to restart their browser or explicitly OK the installation of the ActiveX control.

Is that possible?  Can you install an ActiveX control from outside the browser in such a way that it becomes immediately available to pages running inside the browser? Or should I give up, and allow the user to be explicitly prompted to install the ActiveX control?

Comment: You may be able to install the activeX at the same time as the application.

Comment: That would be fantastic.  Would it become available immediately, without a browser restart?

Comment: I vote for user prompt... what you're asking for creates a security hole that would undoubtedly be exploited